# Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial such that $f(f(x))=f(x-1)f'(x+1)$ and $f'(0)=2$. Find $f(x)$.

Tags: functions, derivatives

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial such that $f(f(x))=f(x-1)f'(x+1)$ and $f'(0)=2$. Find $f(x)$.

Putting $x=-1$, I get $f(f(-1))=f(-2)f'(0)=2f(-2)$

Putting $x=0$, I get $f(f(0))=f(-1)f'(1)$

Also, replacing $x$ by $x+1$, I get $f(f(x+1))=f(x)f'(x+2)$

Not sure if I am getting anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$\deg f(x) = n$ then $\deg f(f(x)) = n^2$ and $\deg f(x-1)f'(x+1) = n + (n-1)$. Hence, $n^2 = n+(n-1)$

Comment: @aarbee this is not correct. The correct degree of $f(f(x))$ is $n^2$, which the other now deleted answer had correctly stated.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, oh yes, thanks, I'll work out differently now.

Comment: it would be $n^2=n+n-1$

Answer (score 1):

From the hint given by @NinadMunshi and @VIVID, I am able to solve the question. Here is the solution:

Degree of $f(f(x))$= degree of $f(x-1)f'(x+1)\implies n^2=n+n-1$, $n$ being the degree of $f(x)$.

So, $n=1\implies  f(x)=ax+b\implies f'(x)=a\implies a=2\implies f(x)=2x+b$

Putting this in $f(f(x))=f(x-1)f'(x+1)$, I get $2(2x+b)+b=(2(x-1)+b)\cdot2\implies b=-4$

So, $f(x)=2x-4$